# Missing Database Connection on cakephp

Tags: php, postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Cannot connect to the cakephp framework database.
The database.php is present and the configurations are properly configured.
But for some reason beyond my knowledge, it cannot connect.

the screen shot of the error:

[image: Attached is the screen shot of the error]

Comment: password for "dmdbuser" is wrong...

Comment: The error message seems to spell out the problem pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Password for `dmbuser`is wrong, as @VaoTsun mentioned.